# Recovering oracle 11g express edition workspace account

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have been working on Oracle 11g expression edition from around 2-3 month. But today I was trying to login to the workspace but every time it is showing as invalid credentials. But I the workspace name and password entered by me are right even I have saved on chrome.

So how can I recover my workspace account?

Answer (score 0):

A "workspace" - in this context - seems to be related to Oracle Application Express. Is it?

If so, login as **admin** into the internal workspace (presuming, of course, that you know admin's password), and then you can reset any other developer's password - including your own.

If you don't know admin's password, there's another option; it presumes that you a) know `SYS` user's password and b) have the `apxchpwd.sql` script available (you do, if you installed Apex; search the disk). Then connect to SQL*Plus and run the named script, e.g.

```
C:\>sqlplus sys@xe as sysdba
SQL> @apxchpwd.sql
```

Once you set admin's password, back to suggestion #1: login as admin (into Apex) and set users's password.

If *nothing* of that helps (or you don't know any of those passwords), then you're pretty much out of luck, as far as I can tell.